# Hosting WWW and RESTful service ont the same machine

Tags: rest, iis, web

Can a WCF RESTful service and a regular site/www service be hosted concurrently?  Or do I need a seperate machine to host WCF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. they can be hosted on the same machine (depending on whether you are using shared hosting).  If you have the permission, you just need to bind them to different ports.

For example, if your website is hosted on port 80 (which is usually the default), then you can create another website on the same machine hosted on port 8080 for the WCF HTTP service.

If your website is a .NET app pool, you can even host the WCF service inside the same app pool as your website, by using a virtual directory.

Also, you can host multiple websites on the same port if you differentiate them by host headers.

Comment: If you use host headers you can host multiple sites on the same port

Comment: @levelnis Yes, that's true as well, I'll update my answer. Thanks.